# PostAsync to /Token returns Internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web Api with a route to the Login Token setup in the Startup.Auth like so:

```
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AllowInsecureHttp = false
        };
```

That should route my api login request to here:

```
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
    {
     Authorize stuff...
    }
```

From my client I'm trying to login and get an access token:

```
        var loginResponse = await client.PostAsync("/Token", loginContent);
```

Using the login content:

```
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        values.Add("grant_type", "password");
        values.Add("username", "usernamehere");
        values.Add("password", "passwordhere");
        var loginContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
```

When I try to step into the PostAsync to /Token to get the access_token back I always get an Internal Server Error.  I'm not even able to step into the api to see what is going on.

If I remove the [Authorize] decoration from the api methods, I can get my data back... I just can't log in.

If I go to the browser and Put the following in the url to test...

```
 https://localhost:44305/Token
```

I get a (400) bad request.  Not sure what to try next.

I have to have the Token Auth working... can't publish without security. ;)

**Update:**

I should add that I'm using a custom UserStore for identity.

**Update 2:**  The client

```
    public static HttpClient GetClient()
    {

        HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Ics2Constants.ICS2APIBaseAddress);
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return Client;
    }
```

Then the using:

```
using (var client = ICS2HttpClient.GetClient())
        {
            //TESTING:
            await ICS2HttpClient.Authenticate(client);

            //... more stuff after authentication 
        }
```

The Authenticate contains the PostAsync...

Comment: Can you add the code where you instantiate client?

Comment: Well, I feel dumb.  I should have been looking at GrantResourceOwnerCredentials for the Token request.  I had some logic in there that needed to be updated based on my custom identity... the old logic failed and returned an internal server error... ExternalLogin was the wrong place to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else makes the same dumb mistakes that I did:

GrantResourceOwnerCredentials is the place the /Token routes to when validating the user / password and dishing out an access token.

In my case the code below is in the Providers directory in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _publicClientId;

    public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        _publicClientId = publicClientId;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
       // use the userManager to find the user, check credentials, grab roles, etc.  
    }
```

I can post more details if anyone needs more help.  I know it was a pain for me to work out all of the details.

One more note.  I wrote custom Identity stuff based on the mySQL identity stuff [here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/AspNet.Identity.MySQL/UserTable.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Authorize attribute should not be placed above any method getting the token it should be anonymous